# Fast search in a h5py or similar hierarchical database

Tags: python, database, h5py

I need a database for an online catalog; if it's possible one dataset per product. And a simple database; that's what I love h5py.

The method `visititems` of groups it's not fast for large files.

```
import h5py

#in memory database. Not relevant for this question, same speed. Yes.
database = h5py.File('db01h5', driver='core', backing_store=False)

#example of 10000 datasets with a deep of 4 group, file/x10/x10/x10/x10dset
for v1 in ('abcdefghij'):
    for v2 in ('abcdefghij'):
        for v3 in ('abcdefghij'):
            for v4 in ('0123456789'):

                database['/' + v1 + '/' + v2 + '/' + v3 + '/' + 'dset' + v4] = (1, 2, 3)


def fu01(a1, a2):
    pass

#visititems applies function fu01(name, object) to each group and dataset 
database.visititems(fu01)
```

With a function that does not evaluates anything (pass) "database.visititems(fu01)" takes 5 seconds. Filtering with basic arguments it takes x2.

My question is how can I search into a large or very large h5py database filtering by characteristics, and very fast(less than 0.1 seconds for 10.000 of products).

Is h5py/hdf5 the correct way, or it's required an sql database like sqlite3?

Or maybe when speed is needed all must be in the same dataset? With the tree path as one element. For example:

```
database['dataset'] = [['root/categorie/subcategorie/productname'], ['2'], ['10$'], ['blue']]
```

And then filtering all products by one "column"(advanced slicing).

I'm new in databases and at this time I'm not interested in databases that work in memory, like reddis or similar; because it's difficult to synchronize changes in the data. But if there is no other solution...

Answer (score 1):

This is not what `hdf` is optimized to do. It is designed to effectively store a small number of very large data sets, and stumbles on a large number of very small data sets.

I think you would be much better off using an actual database of some sort, either relational or not.

You might also want to just build your own tree implementation, what is slow about `visititems` is walking the group/dataset tree of the hdf file.